# How do I make the columns of one table not contain the columns of another table

Tags: sql, triggers, mariadb

I have a database with these two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Photos(
    photoId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    userId INT NOT NULL,
    url VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    uploadDate DATE NOT NULL,
    title VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
    description VARCHAR(400),
    visibility ENUM ('Pública', 'Privada') NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (photoId),
    FOREIGN KEY (userId) REFERENCES Users (userId) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE InappropiateWords(
    inappropiateWordId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    word VARCHAR(80),
    PRIMARY KEY (inappropiateWordId)
);
```

I'm asked to check that the title and/or description of a photo doesn't contain any inappropiate word. I guess I need to create a trigger but I don't know how to do it. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Just a note, tables have _columns_, not _fields_.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: @jarlh I'm using MariaDB - HeidiSQL

Comment: You would use a trigger to prevent "bad" titles from going into the database.  You would use a query to determine if any are there.  Your question is unclear on which you want.

Comment: I want to prevent them @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 1):

This is not a requirement that you can implement at the database level.

If you are really looking to ensure that the "description" or "title" does not contain inappropriate word, then

"What is Inappropriate" has to be defined?. This is step 1. You have a table (table 2) which I assume will store all inappropriate words.

Then when the program that inserts the picture and description/title is invoked, the code needs to take the title and description and parse the words and compare them against the "inappropriate_word" table and then decide which action to take.

The description or title might have a string of words in which case you may have to parse each word and check against the table(2).

This is not a take away solution but at least I hope this helps.

Comment: Would the proposed answer, fit in your scope of what is a definition? Thank you for the insight.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a table variable that loads on page and perform a join to find those values.

```
CREATE TABLE #tbl_LinkedNames(
    Name                 varchar(50)
,   AssociatedNameNbr    varchar(50)
,   userId                  int
,   inappropiateWordId       int
)
INSERT INTO #tbl_LinkedNames(
        NameNbr, AssociatedName, userId, inappropiateWordId )
VALUES 
    ('A0001', 'badword', 1, 4),
    ('A0002', 'wORSEWORD', 2, 5),
    ('A0002', 'BADW00rds', 3, 6),
    ('A1001', 'badw', 4, 1),
    ('A2002', 'lengua', 5, 2),
    ('A3002', 'diferente', 6, 3)

    SELECT * FROM #tbl_LinkedNames
```

From here it is a simple join based off the called stored procedure.

```
SELECT 
* 
FROM

Photos AS p

LEFT JOIN #tbl_LinkedNames AS t_LN ON
   p.userId = t_LN.userID
   AND
   p.inappropiateWordId = t_LN.inappropiateWordId

LEFT JOIN InappropiateWords AS Ip ON
   Ip.inappropiateWordId = t_LN.inappropiateWordId
```